# Trying to understand this solution

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve a question and I got into a few obstacles that I failed to solve, starting off here is the question: [Codeforces - 817D](http://codeforces.com/contest/817/problem/D)

Now I tried to brute force it, using a basic get min and max for each segment of the array I could generate and then keeping track of them I subtract them and add them together to get the final imbalance, this looked good but it gave me a time limit exceeded cause brute forcing n*(n+1)/2 subsegments of the array given n is 10^6 , so I just failed to go around it and after like a couple of hours of not getting any new ideas I decided to see a solution that I could not understand anything in to be honest :/ , here is the solution:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long    
int a[1000000], l[1000000], r[1000000];
    int main(void) {
        int i, j, n;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        ll ans = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            vector<pair<int,int>> v;
            v.push_back({-1,INF});
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)  {
                while (v.back().second <= a[i]) v.pop_back();
                l[i] = v.back().first;
                v.push_back({i,a[i]});
            }
            v.clear();
            v.push_back({n,INF});
            for(i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)  {
                while (v.back().second < a[i]) v.pop_back();
                r[i] = v.back().first;
                v.push_back({i,a[i]});
            }
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)  ans += (ll) a[i] * (i-l[i]) * (r[i]-i);
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)  a[i] *= -1;
        }
        cout << ans;
    }
```

I tried tracing it but I keep wondering why was the vector used , the only idea I got is he wanted to use the vector as a stack since they both act the same(Almost) but then the fact that I don't even know why we needed a stack here and this equation `ans += (ll) a[i] * (i-l[i]) * (r[i]-i);`  is really confusing me because I don't get where did it come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thats a beast of a calculation. I must confess, that i don't understand it completely either. The problem with the brute force solution is, that you have to calculate values or all over again.

In a slightly modified example, you calculate the following values for an input of `2, 4, 1` (i reordered it by "distance")

```
[2, *, *] (from index 0 to index 0), imbalance value is 0; i_min = 0, i_max = 0
[*, 4, *] (from index 1 to index 1), imbalance value is 0; i_min = 1, i_max = 1
[*, *, 1] (from index 2 to index 2), imbalance value is 0; i_min = 2, i_max = 2
[2, 4, *] (from index 0 to index 1), imbalance value is 2; i_min = 0, i_max = 1
[*, 4, 1] (from index 1 to index 2), imbalance value is 3; i_min = 2, i_max = 1
[2, 4, 1] (from index 0 to index 2), imbalance value is 3; i_min = 2, i_max = 1

where i_min and i_max are the indices of the element with the minimum and maximum value. 
For a better visual understanding, i wrote the complete array, but hid the unused values with *
```

So in the last case `[2, 4, 1]`, brute-force looks for the minimum value over all values, which is not necessary, because you already calculated the values for a sub-space of the problem, by calculating `[2,4]` and `[4,1]`. But comparing only the values is not enough, you also need to keep track of the indices of the minimum and maximum element, because those can be reused in the next step, when calculating `[2, 4, 1]`.

The idead behind this is a concept called [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), where results from a calculation are stored to be used again. As often, you have to choose between speed and memory consumption.

So to come back to your question, here is what i understood :

- the arrays `l` and `r` are used to store the indices of the greatest number left or right of the current one
- vector `v` is used to find the last number (and it's index) that is greater than the current one (`a[i]`). It keeps track of rising number series, e.g. for the input `5,3,4` at first the `5` is stored, then the `3` and when the `4` comes, the 3 is popped but the index of 5 is needed (to be stored in `l[2]`)
- then there is this fancy calculation (`ans += (ll) a[i] * (i-l[i]) * (r[i]-i)`). The stored indices of the maximum (and in the second run the minimum) elements are calculated together with the value `a[i]` which does not make much sense for me by now, but seems to work (sorry).
- at last, all values in the array `a` are multiplied by `-1`, which means, the old maximums are now the minimums, and the calculation is done again (2nd run of the outer for-loop over j)

This last step (multiply `a` by `-1`) and the outer for-loop over j are not necessary but it's an elegant way to reuse the code.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: A little trick to improve the complexity, do not make single element set. Their imbalance value is however zero.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But while this does influence the execution time in the "real" world, it does not change the time complexity.